# Calculate pow(int n) with BigDecimal number in different method

Tags: java, bigdecimal, pow

I'm trying to use BigDecimal function pow(int n), and it works fine for me. However, when I enter large numbers it takes more time to calculate which is not good for my algorithm. Is there a faster way to calculate power of numbers and returns exactly, to unlimited precision? Below is an example of my case:

```
    private static BigDecimal decryption(BigDecimal cipherTxt, int dVal){
    return cipherTxt.pow(dVal);
        }
```

When I enter:

- cipherTxt = 11395128
- dVal = 19299953
- 11395128.pow(19299953)

It takes more time, and it is not useful for my program.

Comment: Are you doing modular exponentiation?  If yes, there is a `BigInteger` method for doing that which will be faster than separate `pow` and `mod` calls.   Should you really be using `BigDecimal` for a encryption algorithm??

Comment: Why are you using BigDecimal? This looks like a task for BigInteger.modPow(), not for BigDecimals.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for your replay. I'm just calculating pow not modular exponentiation

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm using BigDecimal in order to return exactly to unlimited precision

Comment: Your values are integers, so use BigInteger (which is also of "unlimited precision"). It is faster than BigDecimal. Use BigInteger if you can, and only BigDecimal if you need fractions. It is easy to convert between these types.

Comment: FWIW, hat timings did you expect? And what takes time? Calculating or printing?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm using it in an encryption algorithm and I need it to compute very fast

Comment: If it must be fast, then don't use BigDecimal. But in cryptography, one generally uses modPow() which is **much** faster.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis many thanks for your replay I'll try that and look the result